# How to use the execution time method with try and catch

Tags: java, execution-time

I am trying to measure the execution time, but i do not know where to but the method is before the try block or inside??

```
ublic static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {

        SearchDetailsDialog dialog = new SearchDetailsDialog(null);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = ((endTime - startTime)/1000);
    System.out.println("the execution time is:");
    System.out.println(totalTime);
}
```

Comment: execution time of which part of your code? You should use `System.nanoTime()` instead to measure execution time.

Comment: That looks okay. Are you having any problem with it?  You could put it in `finally`, too. And `System.nanoTime()` is more precise. Also, if you divide by 1000, you will get only full seconds, so probably 0 most of the time.

Comment: Better to put it in a finally block or an aspect, IMO.

Comment: That code in your example does not look like it would take any amount of time, though.

Comment: it the main of my GUI class am trying to measure the execution time to get the result. but i think i have put it the wrong place!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.  In your case the best is:

```
long startTime= System.nanoTime() ;
try {
    SearchDetailsDialog dialog = new SearchDetailsDialog(null);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    long endTime= System.nanoTime() ;
    double totalTime= ((double)(endTime - startTime)/1000000000) ;
    System.out.printf("the execution time is: %.3f seconds",totalTime);
}
```

Comment: Added @Thilo's excellent suggestion about nanoTime and used `printf`

Comment: Thank you so much it works. I have another question where to put this method if i want to measure how tong it would take to get a result of search in GUI. Do I have to put in the search class or in the main of GUI??

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in a finally block :

```
long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = ((endTime - startTime)/1000);
    System.out.println("the execution time is:");
    System.out.println(totalTime);
```

Comment: And use System.nanoTime.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with nanoTime() if available but I would put both start and stop time captures between try and catch, that mechanism eats some time too. Alternatively you can capture stop time at two points (second within catch block).. println() anywhere ...

Comment: and how to use that u mean to put System.nanoTime() instead of System.currentTimeMillis();??